# Entity Framework Core 3.0 - Update an entities navigation property without first deleting or loading and then inserting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update an entity `Contact`'s navigational property `Subjects`. This is a collection of `Subject`s.

My intention is for entity framework to detect that if I have only 2 subjects in this list, but the database has 5 subjects, i want to delete the 3 subjects which are not present in the list.

I have acheived that using the code below.

```
// The entity we wish to update.
var contact = locationContact.Contact;

// Attach it and set all properties to modified.
_db.Update(contact);

// Since its an update, we haven't provided this property and don't want it to be changed, so unset IsModified.
_db.Entry(contact).Property(x => x.RegisteredUtc).IsModified = false;

// Set the updated subjects to a temporary list
var updatedSubjects = new List<ContactSubject>(contact.Subjects);

// Load the current subjects list
await _db.Entry(contact).Navigation("Subjects").LoadAsync();

// Replace it with the new list, so changes are detected
contact.Subjects = updatedSubjects;

// Save the changes
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My concern is the call to `LoadAsync()` - If I'm updating hundreds of `Contact`s it could cause a big slowdown.

I've tried setting `IsLoaded` on `Subjects` as opposed to calling `LoadAsync` but it didn't work.

Likewise, I've tried setting `IsModified` on `Subjects` but it didn't work.

There must be a way to ask EF:

> *Please consider the list I have provided for this navigation property as what I wish to exist in the database. If an entry exists in the list but not in the database, add that entry. If an entry exists in the database but not in the list, delete that entry.*

Does anyone know a more performant way to do this than what I have done above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can build a simple where clause on the child table, you can load multiple records at once.

```cs
// capture all the modified contact.Subjects relationships.
// Assuming contacts is some IEnumerable<> of contact.GetType()
var newValues = contacts.Select(c => (contact = c, c.Subjects)).ToList();
// Re-load them all from the database
await _db.Subjects.Where(s => ...).LoadAsync();
// Reset them all again
foreach((var contact, var subjects) in newValues)
   contact.Subjects = subjects;
```

The trick is building the where clause. If you already have some criteria you used to fetch the contacts, re-use that. eg;

```cs
...Where(s => s.Contact.OtherFK == value);
```

However, personally I wouldn't do it that way. I'd keep track of each records `EntityState`, Added / Unchanged / Modified / Deleted and re-attach them to the context. Otherwise how are you going to deal with concurrency issues?

Comment: If I was feeling adventurous, I'd write an extension LoadAll<P,C>(DbContext context, IEnumerable<P> parents, Expression<Func<P,C>> navigation). That might internally call context.Entry(c).Collection(navigation).Query() on each value, merge the where clauses into a single query, then load it. However a hand written where clause can be much simpler.